# Remove spot left by sun lamp on surface

Tags: blender-internal-render-engine, light

[image]

*Note that I am a noob before answering*.

I have attached an image of an Earth that I'm creating. I want to remove the glare of the glossy reflection on the surface of the Earth in the center.

Is there a way to do this in Blender Render?

Thanks, Greg

Comment: so both answers should work, removing the specularity either from the material or at the light source. Make your choice considering this: is there more than one object receiving rays from this lamp ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Select the lamp. In the *Properties panel > Object data tab > Lamp dropdown*, uncheck *Specular*. It's checked in the following photo because it came from [blender.org](https://www.blender.org/manual/render/blender_render/lighting/lights/light_properties.html). I would use my own screenshot, but I am away from my computer at the moment.

[image]

Comment: Hallelujah!  Thank you very much Shady Puck.  Looks great!

Comment: @GregKlein If my answer helped, please consider accepting it by clicking on the green checkmark at the top left of my answer. It would help me greatly and make be very happy!

Answer (score 1):

In the material of the sphere,decrease the specular intensity.

[image: Material]